# Migrating a wordpress site and getting err_connection_refused

Tags: wordpress

I'm transfering a wordpress site from a previous hosting package to our inhouse servers.  I've copied the whole directory and taken a .sql backup of the database.  Before moving it onto our servers, I want to make sure it works by running the backup locally.

So i've imported the database and changed the siteurl and home fields in the wp_options table to match my localhost.  When i go to it, I get a database error, Which is what I wanter so then I  entered the correct details in wp_config

But now when I go there, I get err_connection_refused message.  I've tried everything I can think of, the url is correct in the database wp_options table so its not that.  Any ideas please on what to try next?

Comment: Are you trying to reach the site on a specific port on your localhost?

Comment: Just standard Port 80

Comment: The local DB user has "all" privileges to the locate database where you imported the live server's database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not leave everything as is, and edit your *hosts* file to point to your new machine.

Then you can test using the real URL, minimizing the risk that there are URLs in the database that you didn't edit while testing.

Comment: The URL is currently pointing to the Wordpress site on the original host.  This needs to remain live and uninterupted until I'm ready to switch the URL to the IP address of the new server

Comment: I understand, but if you edit YOUR *hosts* file, then only YOUR machine will point to the new site, while everybody else will see the old site.